# string split function returning ['\n'] python

Tags: python, string, split

So you see I am making a simple gui in which when I write 'p- ' and then a value, it opens up a tkinter gui with the value. Most of the part is done but after fixing a few errors, I ran into another one. What happened is that the string split function returned ['\n'] **not** ['p- ', 'value']. Also since I am thinking of expanding this program I have used the names accordingly.

I tried searching the web for a solution and well...I found nothing

```
for keyword in keyword_list.values():
        global isSplit
        isSplit = False 
        value_list = input.split(keyword)
        print(value_list)
        value_list.remove(keyword)
        values = str(value_list)
        isSplit = True
        
        if isSplit and values is not None and keyword is not None:
            return values, isSplit, keyword
        else:
            print("something went wrong")
```

I put this code inside a function in a util file. Then in my shell file (where is the gui code) I made another function. Firstly I use the code in this function to return 3 variables then I use them and create tkinter window with a label which's text is the 'value' variable I am returning in the above code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are splitting on `keyword`. I would expect someone to split on a kind of divider to get keywords.

Comment: What is you input?
You could try to remove the "\n" from the input with a space

Comment: `input.split` is not a function. `str.split` does split on \n line endings (on linux at least). I'd strongly recommend editing to show the exact function being run and an example input that is getting thrown off.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how `split` works. if your string is `p-foo\n` and you split on `foo` then foo gets removed and the returns list will be `['p-', '\n']`. also, dont use `input` as a variable, you are overwriting pythons `input` function, unless you means to split ht literal input from the user in which case it would be `input().split(...)`

Comment: Well... If split works like how @Nullman is saying then I am using 'p- ' as my keyword and I am supposed to get ['foo', '\n']

Comment: not quite. again, if the string is `'p-foo\n'` then doing `split('p-')` will return `['foo\n']`. you can remove the '\n' if you run your string through `strip` first i.e. `my_string.strip().split(...)`

Comment: But thats exactly what is not happening. You see foo is replacing the word I type after p-  in the text box. But split() is not returning what i typed. Instead, it is returning just '\n'.

Like if i type 'p- Hello World' then it returns ['\n']

Comment: can't be, there must be a misunderstanding somewhere.  `'p- Hello World\n'.strip().split('p-')` will return `['', ' Hello World']`. the first empty string is because your string starts with the delimiter, if you want to avoid having it then you can change your code to `[item for item in 'p- Hello World\n'.strip().split('p-') if item]` which will then return `[' Hello World']`